# Palindrome excluding special characters and spaces

Tags: c++, string, palindrome

I have written a code for checking if a string is palindrome or not which should exclude white spaces and special characters and should be case in-sensitive. So the function isPalindrome(string A) takes in a string and returns 1 if its a palindrome and 0 if its not.

For example: input: A man, a plan, a canal: Panama
             output: 1
Below is the code-

```
int isPalindrome(string A) {
    string::iterator it;
    string::reverse_iterator rit;
    it=A.begin();
    rit=A.rbegin();
    while(it!=A.end() && rit!=A.rend()){
        while(!isalnum(*rit))       //if char from the end is not alphanumeric, then increment the reverse iterator till we find the alphanumeric char. 
            ++rit;
        while(!isalnum(*it))       //if char from the start is not alphanumeric, then increment the iterator till we find the alphanumeric char. 
            ++it;
        if(tolower(*it)!=tolower(*rit))  //case in-sensitive comparison
            return 0;
        ++it;
        ++rit;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

It works well for all the variations of input like `A man, a plan, a canal: Panama"` or `"A man, a plan, a canal: Panama` but when I input `"A man, a plan, a canal: Panama"` it fails with run time error.

So please let me know where am I going wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You forgot to check if there is the end in the inner `while`. As already said, you cannot develop without debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that both iterators might have reached the end in the nested while loops, there should be checking for this.

```
int isPalindrome(string A) {
    string::iterator it;
    string::reverse_iterator rit;
    it=A.begin();
    rit=A.rbegin();
    while(it!=A.end() && rit!=A.rend()){
        while(rit != A.rend() && !isalnum(*rit))       //if char from the end is not alphanumeric, then increment the reverse iterator till we find the alphanumeric char. 
            ++rit;
        while(it != A.end() && !isalnum(*it))       //if char from the start is not alphanumeric, then increment the iterator till we find the alphanumeric char. 
            ++it;

        if (it == A.end() || rit == A.rend())
            break;

        if(tolower(*it)!=tolower(*rit))  //case in-sensitive comparison
            return 0;
        ++it;
        ++rit;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You should at least explain what was wrong and what you fixed, rather than providing bare code.